# 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_',this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Oblig1.Models.Item]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am currently getting the error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_546F9926F8DC53E2EF66BA48BE431DF1B26DEBEFA54B0597E60AEB1839DD022C', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Oblig1.Models.Item]'."

I am trying to list out the view _Minside.html with a single User but keep getting this error, anyone who could lend a helping hand?

_Minside.html:

```
@model Oblig1.Models.User

<table class="table">
    @Model.Firstname
    @Model.Surname
    @Model.Email
    @Model.Address
    @Model.Password
    @Model.Phonenr
    @Model.Postcode
</table>
```

This is a partial which comes through Minside.html:

```
@model Oblig1.Models.User
<br />
<br />
<br />

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kontoinformasjon</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Ordrehistorikk</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <br />
        <br />

        @Html.Partial("_Minside")

    </div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Ordrehistorikk</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

This view is opened by the link in the view _Layout which contains this model:

```
@model IEnumerable<Oblig1.Models.Item>
@Html.ActionLink("  MinSide", "Minside", "", new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user" })
```

UserController:

```
    public ActionResult Minside()
    {
        var db = new PastaContext();

        string compareEmail = (string)Session["User"];
        User foundUser = db.Users.Find(compareEmail);

        if(foundUser == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(foundUser);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: You are passing a single `User` object into your view but the view is expecting an `IEnumerable<Item>`

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to add that i only want to list 1 user in the _Minside view! Will update question now.

Comment: Try to change `@Html.Partial("_Minside")` to `@Html.RenderAction("Minside","UserController")`.